# Can I download my minecraft directory from my Google Cloud server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I am trying to download my minecraft world, which is in a folder titled name@minecraft2019:~/minecraft$

Somehow the only bucket I have, is empty, and I have no idea where the files are stored. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Debian Linux for minecraft server on GCE Minecraft files should be stored in below location.

/home/YOURNAME/.minecraft/.

You can also take backup using Cloud Storage Standard Storage bucket. Please follow the link[1] to create a backup.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server#schedule_backups